# auto generate form name using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, css

i was trying to auto generate from ids on my page, i dont know how possible this is.
e.g

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="" id="">
</form>
```

i have searched the internet and i came acrossand i got this

```
h1 { counter-reset: section; }
```

for displaying numbers on every h1 elements

so my intention is for every form that was added to the page an id was appended to it.

i know it might sound weird but i rili need help on this

Comment: did you try `id="<?php echo $someid; ?>"` inside id attribute of form

Comment: no javascript or css can do that?

Comment: No, not CSS. JS can but...why? You are _already_ generating values for the form attributes in PHP, what is the reason to *not* continue doing it? `id="<?php echo 'myId' . $someid++; ?>"` is sufficient if you have many forms on the page.